# Skype installation problem in Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS

Tags: apt, skype

I tried to install **Skype** by using below commands:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```

On Ubuntu 16.04 but it shows error saying:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package skype:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
skype-bin:i386

E: Package 'skype:i386' has no installation candidate.
```

How can I solve the problem and install Skype?

Comment: Please try this command: `sudo apt install skype-bin:i386`

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below:

1) Download deb package of skype from source (I'm taking from https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.deb)

2) Install GDebi package Installer from ubuntu software center or from command line.

3) Install the downloaded deb package of skype with GDebi package Installer.

Note: you can also try with dpkg -i  but sometimes it stucks in resolving dependencies so I prefer to go with GDebi package Installer.

Comment: you can accept answer and upvote it if it worked for you.